# Finding permutation matrix $P$ that minimizes the trace of $P C P^T D$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, mathematics-education

I have a problem that is really important for my thesis and i am not studding math so i will be very glad if you help me in this case...
 thanks for your help in advance

I want to find permutation matrix $P$ which minimizes $\mathrm{trace}(P C P^T D)$, when $C$ and $D$ are given quadratic symmetric matrices.

sorry if its not clear enough

in the link below i found a similar question but there is a bit difference and that is that here we work with permutation matrices.but sorrily i can not come to conclusion:(

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/239352/200836

Comment: What does that minimization problem mean? Are you minimizing some kind of a matrix norm? Take a look at this formatting guide to make the question clearer: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/166535

Comment: thanks for your comment, we have C and D matrices and we want to find permutation which minimizes the Trace. is there any better way than checking all permutation matrices?

Comment: I edited your question into a more standard form. For one thing, never use $I$ for any matrix other than an identity matrix unless you want to confuse every mathematician who is watching. I think your question is quite hard.

Answer (score 6):

This is the well-known problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_assignment_problem

In general there is no efficient algorithm known for this problem. A much more famous Travelling Salesman Problem is a particular case...

Comment: is there any better way than checking all possible permutations?

Comment: well, there was a lot of research done on this problem. it would not be necessary to check a fraction of all permutations of n symbols, but still nobody knows how to check less than exponentially (in terms of n) many of them.

Comment: i.e. instead of n! permutations you might still need to check something like $2^n$ of them.

Comment: you might like to check out http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7721 for up to date references etc